# Calling public PHP function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I wrote a public function to create a project, but I need to call it in my JavaScript file. How can I do this?

This is the public function I want to use in `data.php`:

```php
public function create($projectid,$projectnaam,$startdatum,$einddatum,$omschrijving)
{
  try
  {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO projects (projectid, projectnaam, startdatum, einddatum, omschrijving) VALUES (".$projectid.",'".$projectnaam."', '".$startdatum."', '".$einddatum."', '".$omschrijving."')";
    $stmt->bindparam(":projectid",$projectid);
    $stmt->bindparam(":projectnaam",$projectnaam);
    $stmt->bindparam(":startdatum",$startdatum);
    $stmt->bindparam(":einddatum",$einddatum);
    $stmt->bindparam(":einddatum",$omschrijving);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();  
    return false;
  }

}
```

This is the row I am using in my JavaScript to call the function but it's not working:

```
url:          'data.php?create',
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly you can not call any php function, but what you can do it - pass any parameter to php file in ajax url, fetch its value in php file beginning, and call function if value matche.

ex.

in ajax:

```
url:          'data.php?data=create'
```

in php file at beginning:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
if($data == "create")
   create(); // call create function
```

Comment: But my data.php is written in OOP, so where do i need to call this $data = $_GET['data'];
if($data == "create")
   create(); // call create function ??

Comment: You directly can not call any clasa method actually. You need to create object of that class and then try to call method.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var foo= "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
</script>
```

otherwise you cannot directly call a php function in js

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a single core php file which you include in every php page, right? I usually use to have a PHP classes autoloader, so I don't have to deal with include/require of classes.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    /* Here you can do all of your test if file/dir exists or not */
    include $class_name . '.php'; //then, you include it only when really used
});
```

I would build the class like:

```
class Maker {

    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_GET['create']){
            /* fetch params */
            $this->create(/*....params....*/);
        }
    }

    public function create($projectid,$projectnaam,$startdatum,$einddatum,$omschrijving){
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

and in your core file add simply:

```
// this will listen for GET parameter 'create' and will fire create(...) function
$maker = new Maker();
```

In this way, you can just make an ajax request to any of your files, and your function will be executed. Pay attention at outputs and errors

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'core.php?create'
});
```